# fieldset not appears properly on ipad in landscape mode

Tags: html, ipad, safari, fieldset, landscape-portrait

I have an asp.net web page. It has a fieldset to it.I visit this page in safari on my iPad. In portrait mode it is correct. As in, I can see the fieldset and functionality of page is also correct. I tilt the ipad to Landscape and the fieldset disappears.

[Snapshot of how the page looks in POTRAIT MODE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40597849/photob4.png)

When in landscape mode I noticed that the fieldset is present but very light. Here is a link for landscape mode.

[Snapshot after moving it into LANDSCAPE mode](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40597849/photo1.PNG).

If  you look closely for landscape there is a faint line on "Filters" And "Customer Info Panel". How can i correct it to get the page to have the field set in both modes?

The code  where I have fieldset is:

```
  <table style="background-color:#EFEFEF;  border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; width:510px;">
            <fieldset style="border:solid;border-color:brown;" onclick="">
                <legend style="text-align: center">FILTERS</legend>

                <table cellspacing="5" style="text-align: left; table-layout:fixed;" >
                   <tr>
                      .....
```

EDIT: This also happens on Chrome browser on iPad.

If you need more info,please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't need more info per se, but I am encountering the same problem. On my iPad, perfectly styled fieldsets only show in Safari in portrait mode, not landscape. This problem only cropped up a few hours ago after installing iOS7.  :-(  Viewing this page (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) exhibits the problem as well.

Comment: @ChrisValdivia. I tried working with a blank page and a field set but it did not work. So I ended up using div tag and created a border for it and put my label underneath it. My clients liked it.

Answer (score 2):

here the solution for tag fieldset:

`<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`

if you add other property (eg width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0) into content attribute it won't work properly..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your problem can be solved by defining a viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Wonderful - that made the frameset border appear in both modes! Unfortunately though, this prevents things from rescaling properly when switching orientations.